# toString from another java project prints type name

Tags: java, project, tostring

So I know the thing about overriding "toString" to see what you want instead of the type, but in my case the overall picture is:

`Project1:ClassA` uses `Project2:ClassB` where I included `Project2` into `Project1` classpath and compilation works fine.But, the `Project2:ClassB.toString()` prints `project2.package.classC` instead of the classC elements of classB.

Note, once I copy classB into project1, the printing works fine and I see the elements.

Here is a snapshot of classB from project2 that I'm using in my current project1:

```
package edu.cs;
public class FeatureWeightArrayWritable implements Writable {//classB

    public int vectorSize;
    public FeatureWeight[] vector; //classC = FeatureWeight

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < this.vectorSize; i++)
            buffer.append(vector[i].feature + " " + vector[i].weight);
        // return buffer.toString();
        return "Can't see this !!! I see edu.cs.FeatureWeight@32829 ";
    }
}
```

and if you're suspicious about `FeatureWeight` class, I also override its toString, but it should not be even used if I had the return message as above. Any clues?

Here is how I read it:

```
Reader reader = new SequenceFile.Reader(fs, inputPath, conf);

Writable key = (Writable) reader.getKeyClass().newInstance();
FeatureWeightArrayWritable value = new FeatureWeightArrayWritable();

while (reader.next(key, value))     
    System.out.println("key:" + key.toString() + ", value:" + value.toString());
```

Comment: Where is the code where `toString()` is getting called?

Comment: edu.cs.FeatureWeight@32829 looks exactly like a default implementation of toString().   Considering that it prints edu.cs.FeatureWeight and NOT edu.cs.FeatureWeightArrayWritable@????? I would say that you are not calling it on correct object. Are you using (casting to) FeatureWeight class somewhere?

What is the actual output that you get? And what is the code that alls it?

Comment: Are you sure you're printing the right thing?

Comment: Thanks for you questions, I hope my clarifications are enough now :)

Comment: From your write-up, are we to assume that the `value` is the problem, and that the `key` is printing fine?

Comment: Yes, key is not an issue because it's a built-in type "LongWritable" so can be found from one jar not written by me :)

Answer (score 0):

Check your classpath, and make sure you don't have another copy (old class file, jar file, a 3rd project, etc) of `FeatureWeightArrayWritable` laying around somewhere.

Comment: Thank you all, and Richard seems to be right because it works fine when I "extract Runnable Jar" in eClipse but the above error was when using ant and my defined build.xml. I still didn't find where is the other duplicate is from my build.xml.